# Dynamic input elements in React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am trying to add dynamic input boxes to a form. Here is the Scenario

User should be able to add fields to the form with desire name and value:

Step1 . Create a blank form

Step2. From External(Outside the form) inbox user should give the name of the field and initial value of that field

Step 3 . When User clicks on the button that is outside the form , react hook form should automatically create a field inside itself and assign default value to the respective input box

Step 4 . Now if i change the value inside the react hook form that should affect the react hook forms change and dirty state variables

Any leads? Need to complete this using React Hook Form.

Comment: Check this out: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/09/29/react-dynamic-form-example-with-react-hook-form

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.